# Setting up Zendesk as a remote Service Provider in OpenAm

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, openam, zendesk

Am trying to register Zendesk as a remote service provider in OpenAm server.
I have a problem with finding a metadata file or a url for Zendesk. Is it even needed, if so how can I fill that field.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct the SAML metadata manually, something like this should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<EntityDescriptor entityID="myorganization.zendesk.com" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
    <SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="false" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</NameIDFormat>
        <AssertionConsumerService index="1" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://myorganization.zendesk.com/access/saml"/>
    </SPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```